# Why did shell redirection fail?

Tags: linux, shell

The command causing the failure,

```
gpc xxx.pas > error.txt
```

Because I want to upload the error message to the stackflow.com,but it turns out there is nothing in the error.txt,moreover the gpc still cried to the stdout and print the error message one the screen?

So why would shell redirection fail?

thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

STDERR (standard error) in UNIX and UNIX-like systems is redirected using `2>` instead of a single chevron (`>`).

example:

```
gpc xxx.pas 2> error.txt
```

This will allow standard output (STDOUT) to be printed to the terminal like normal, but send all error messages to the file, `error.txt`.

If you want to collect both STDOUT and STDERR in the same file, use `2>&1`: this tells the shell to copy STDERR (`2`) to STDOUT (`1`).  Now redirecting STDOUT gets both streams:

```
gpc xxx.pas 2>&1 > stdout-and-stderr.txt
```

Comment: I'll add that programs can output content to both STDOUT and STDERR.

They don't often choose wisely.

Consider what the program would output by default.

For a compiler, I consider programming errors to be "output"; REAL errors would be stuff like "filesystem full; cannot write file" or "file not found" or "library corrupt" or stuff like that.  So it's pretty sad that a programming error goes out on STDERR.

Note that the redirection directives are different for csh/tcsh than from bash which is what is given in the example above.

Comment: @John T: please replace "UNIX and UNIX-like systems" by "/bin/sh and Bourne shell-like shells" -  csh and derivatives dosn't support this.